# pytest: how to use a fixture to parametrize

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

in `conftest.py` there is a fixture defined that returns a list:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def targets_to_try():
    with open(
        "{}/xxx/cicd/xxx/manifest.yaml".format(os.environ["APPFOLDER"]), "rt"
    ) as f:
        manifest = yaml.safe_load(f.read())
        schema = Manifest.ManifestSchema()
        appobj = schema.load(manifest)
        return appobj.data["targets_to_try"]
```

In test file `test_interfaces_cfg.py` I would like to use the above fixture in order to parametrize the test function

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("target", targets_to_try)
def test_interfaces_cfg(manifest, target):
    pass
```

This causes the following error:

```
E   NameError: name 'targets_to_try' is not defined
```

Could you please advise how to achieve the desired behaviour ?

**EDIT:** if `targets_to_try()` is not a fixture in `conftest.py` then I get the following error:

```
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("target", targets_to_try())
E   NameError: name 'targets_to_try' is not defined
```

**EDIT:** directory layout is as follows:

```
$ tree
.
|-- attributes
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- bgp
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- Blueprint.py
|-- communities
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- conftest.py
|-- customize
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- Head.py
|-- interfaces
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- test_interfaces_configlet.py
|-- InterfacesIx.py
|-- InterfacesLacp.py
|-- manifest
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- test_schema.py
|-- Manifest.py
|-- NeighborIx.py
|-- policies
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- prefixes
|   `-- __init__.py
|-- pytest.ini
|-- Stack.py
`-- Tail.py
```

Comment: Passing fixtures as parameters into `parametrize` is not supported in `pytest`, see the issue [Using fixtures in pytest.mark.parametrize](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/349). Since your fixture does not depend on anything, just call it like a plain function: `@pytest.mark.parametrize('target', targets_to_try())`.

Comment: thanks @hoefling but i do not think that is possible, see EDIT

Comment: Of course if you want to call a function in python, you have to import it first. Maybe it's even wise to extract the fixture code into a function in some `utils` module and the fixture calling it. Then you can use the function from `utils` for parametrizing and the fixture for the rest.

Comment: but the tests are located in directories that are 1-level down that `conftest.py` see directory layout above (EDIT), so they can't import any potential `utils.py` hence the mechanism with the fixtures, right ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. If you want to use the fixture function as a regular function and call it at the point of your choice, then simply import it and use it as you would with any other Python function. If you would like to use this fixture with the corresponding test, then add its name as the test function's parameter, as you would with any other fixture. There is no need to use `parametrize` for any of these use cases.